# Unable to project the anonymous type to model type. (The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I want to display the selective information from 3 tables.
I have tried DTO but unable to represent the data in a view.
I have tried also using a anonymous type but unable to project it to the model of type InboxViewModelDTO.

Below is the ActionResult,

```
    public ActionResult Inbox()
    {
        IEnumerable<InboxViewModelDTO> model = null;

        AccountDbContext db = new AccountDbContext();
        int? currentUserID = 0;
        currentUserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);

        model = (from a in db.rommateDatabase
                         join b in db.userAccounts on a.UserID equals b.UserId
                         join c in db.messaging on b.UserId equals c.FromUserID
                         where b.UserId == currentUserID
                        select new InboxViewModelDTO()
                        // select new
                         { 
                            UserID = b.UserId,
                            FirstName = b.FirstName,
                            LastName = b.LastName,
                            RequestID = a.ID,
                            MessageMail = c.MessageMail
                         }).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

I have created a DTO class

```
public class InboxViewModelDTO
{
  [Key]
  public int MessageID {get;set;}
  public int UserID { get; set; }       
  public string FirstName { get; set; }        
  public string LastName { get; set; }        
  public int RequestID { get; set; }      
  public string MessageMail { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is the View

```
 @model List<RegistrationLogin.Models.InboxViewModelDTO> @foreach (var
 item in Model) {
     <tr>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestID)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MessageMail)
         </td>
     </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
   model = (from a in db.rommateDatabase
                         join b in db.userAccounts on a.UserID equals b.UserId
                         join c in db.messaging on b.UserId equals c.FromUserID
                         where b.UserId == currentUserID
                         select new 
                         { 
                            UserID = b.UserId,
                            FirstName = b.FirstName,
                            LastName = b.LastName,
                            RequestID = a.ID,
                            MessageMail = c.MessageMail
                         }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new InboxViewModelDTO {
                            UserID = x.UserID ,
                            FirstName = x.FirstName ,
                            LastName = x.LastName,
                            RequestID = x.RequestID ,
                            MessageMail = x.MessageMail
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks Jitendra :)